# Convert MATLAB code to a library

Tags: c#, matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

How can i convert a MATLAB code to a library to be used from a C# project ?

Is MATLAB Compiler / Coder the only way, because they require a license which you need to buy in order to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using Matlab code from c# like in this link

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-matlab-function-from-c-client.html?refresh=true

Answer (score 0):

You should use a tool / library which offers similar syntax and similar functionality - but is purely a .NET library. It not only gains you a much simpler transition to your production ready code. It also gives you much more stable and faster results. Not to speak from [Visual Studio integration](http://ilnumerics.net/visualstudio-extension.html)...

Disclaimer: I am with [ILNumerics](http://ilnumerics.net).

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what version you are using.

You will need to use `mcc` or the MatLab .Net Builder